# How to filter based on the date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I had a query as below in my function. In that I need to filter based on the a.submit_date

```
SELECT mail_id , mail_async, mail_priority FROM glms_mail_sys_mail_store a
WHERE                  
--(TO_DATE(a.submit_date,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm') >= '14-06-2012 18:30')
--AND (TO_DATE(a.submit_date,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm') <= '15-06-2012 18:50')

(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(a.submit_date,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'),'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm') >= '14-06-2012 18:30')
AND (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(a.submit_date,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'),'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm') <= '15-06-2012 18:30')
```

In My DB a.submit_date had a value as '14-06-2012 20:30'

But its throwing Invalid month... can anyone help to correct this?

Comment: @rs - Nope, he needs HH24, not HH.

Comment: yes i realized and updated it

Comment: @rs - Yep, saw your update after my post :).  We're just out of sync :).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, try this below, it works:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('14-06-2012 20:30','dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI') FROM dual
```

Then, you need to convert the right side of the inequalities to dates.

```
a.submit_date >= TO_DATE('14-06-2012 18:30','dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI') AND
a.submit_date <= TO_DATE('15-06-2012 18:50','dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI')
```

If you want to write it a bit cleaner, use `BETWEEN` instead:

```
a.submit_date BETWEEN
  TO_DATE('14-06-2012 18:30','dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI') AND
  TO_DATE('15-06-2012 18:50','dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI')
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a complete example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (submit_date DATE);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES (to_date('14-06-2012 20:30','dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (to_date('14-07-2012 20:30','dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI'));

SELECT * FROM foo a
WHERE
a.submit_date BETWEEN
  TO_DATE('14-06-2012 18:30','dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI') AND
  TO_DATE('15-06-2012 18:50','dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI')
```

Output:

```
    SUBMIT_DATE
1   6/14/2012 8:30:00 PM
```

Comment: Thank you all for ur responses.. but this query doesn't return any rows ,, since i had a row with a.submit_date  as '14-06-2012 20:30'

Comment: @java Programmer - Yeah, you want to use submit_date instead of the to_date for the left side of the inequality. I updated the answer, and included a complete, working example. Hope it helps.